# Using Twitter OAuth Echo for verify_credential, how can I get email?

Tags: php, android, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have mobile app, and I need to registrate user with twitter.

I'm getting params X-Auth-Service-Provider and X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization for [OAuth Echo](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/echo) and send them to server

Server calls [verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) and gets Twitter User Profile.

But this profile does not contain user's email, how can I get user's email at backend, while authorizing user in mobile app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To request a user’s email address, your application needs to be whitelisted by Twitter. To do that, you need:

1. Fill the following [form](https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform) on the Twitter API Policy Support.
2. Select the `I need access to special permissions` option.
3. You'll need to fill your application name and ID (you can fetch these from https://apps.twitter.com).
4. In the permission list, select the permissions you need. In your case, it should be `Email address`.
5. Submit

Once your request is approved or if you're already whitelisted, you can go back to https://apps.twitter.com and under the app permissions section, a new checkbox `Request email addresses from users` will be available. You'll need to enable this new option. The Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL fields will also be available.

At this point, you can add the `include_email` parameter to your `account/verify_credentials` request.

Some related points:

- Users will be informed that your app is requesting the email address during the login process.
- You'll only get verified email addresses, if the user did not provide any email address or did not verify it, you'll get `null`.
- If you already have authenticated users, you'll need to regenerate the user access token to get the email address.

Comment: regenerating user token helped, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If your app is whitelisted as suggested https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials

or as suggested by @Hideo

At server side You can us

GET Request  for: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true

with following type auth 1.0 http header

```
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="KgpUD2nx5UCH9DllSIM4D****",
                oauth_nonce="77252745154355061291979480247359",
                oauth_signature="jPd5e5Z5ibKDb40JUjAuDVpi9TU%3D",
                oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",       oauth_timestamp="1471161684",
                oauth_token="76472850016308****-qOqGdpxuVvT7Z7s5n9NFXqzIr11****",
                oauth_version="1.0"
```

Here oauth_token will be obtained access token as suggested here http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor12

You will get following type of response:

```
{
  "id": 75534037587985****,
  "id_str": "75534037587985****",
  "name": "tester",
  "screen_name": "*********",
  "location": "",
  "description": "",
  "url": null,
  "entities": {
    "description": {
      "urls": []
    }
  },
  "protected": false,
  "followers_count": 0,
  "friends_count": 19,
  "listed_count": 0,
  "created_at": "Tue Jul 19 09:55:54 +0000 2016",
  "favourites_count": 0,
  "utc_offset": null,
  "time_zone": null,
  "geo_enabled": false,
  "verified": false,
  "statuses_count": 0,
  "lang": "en",
  "contributors_enabled": false,
  "is_translator": false,
  "is_translation_enabled": false,
  "profile_background_color": "F5F8FA",
  "profile_background_image_url": null,
  "profile_background_image_url_https": null,
  "profile_background_tile": false,
  "profile_image_url": "http://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png",
  "profile_image_url_https": "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_4_normal.png",
  "profile_link_color": "2B7BB9",
  "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
  "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
  "profile_text_color": "333333",
  "profile_use_background_image": true,
  "has_extended_profile": false,
  "default_profile": true,
  "default_profile_image": true,
  "following": false,
  "follow_request_sent": false,
  "notifications": false,
  "email": "testerdaff@gmail.com"
}
```

Let me know if you have any concerns.